# Ubuntu server 16.04 with minimal xubuntu - xorg.conf overwritten on each boot

Tags: nvidia, xubuntu, xorg

I am testing mining setup with 2 two P106-100 cards. There is also integrated intel card with connected monitor.

I've installed kernel 4.14, and nvidia-384 drivers. I am trying to overclock cards and manually set fan speed.

I am trying same thing in xubuntu, but problem is that my xorg.conf gets overwritten on each reboot.

Question is what is making xorg.conf being overwritten each time. How to prevent this from happening?

I tried `chattr +i /etc/X11/xorg.conf`, X won't start. Commenting gpu-manager.conf also does not help.

What I see is that xorg.conf is overwritten from hybrid-performance file, if it exists. Otherwise, it is created from scratch, and not correctly.

**2018-01-25**

I fixed issue about copying with installing only nvidia drivers (384.111), which install only lightdm with itself, and stopped overwriting my xorg.conf.

Now, another issues is that with some cards `nvidia-settings -q all` returns empty string. No option is available. I tried to search for solution, but I am not sure if it is ubuntu or drivers related.

Comment: Practically, I want to run 2 GPUs headless, but nvidia-xconfig generated xorg.conf is overwritten each time. I am not sure what is the problem, and I am kinda hitting the wall, as I tried most of solutions I managed to find.

Comment: @DavidFoerster Please let me know if this makes more sense. Thank you very much.